# Go error checking and chaining

Tags: go, error-handling

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type FieldElement struct {
    Num   int
    Prime int
}

func (el *FieldElement) Add(o FieldElement) (FieldElement, error) {
    if el.Prime != o.Prime {
        return FieldElement{}, errors.New("cannot operate on two numbers in different Fields")
    }
    return FieldElement{(el.Num + o.Num) % el.Prime, el.Prime}, nil
}

// Sub, Mul, Div and Pow also members of FieldElement returning (FieldElement, error)

func main() {
    a := FieldElement{13, 19}
    b := FieldElement{9, 19}
    fmt.Println(a.Add(b))
}

type Point struct {
    X        FieldElement
    Y        FieldElement
    A        FieldElement
    B        FieldElement
}
```

Now upon `Point` creation I want to check if a point is on the curve defined as `y^2 = x^3 + ax + b`

Each operation of FieldElement returns 2 values to satisfy the error checking.

So I can not do

```
x.Pow(3).Add(a.Mul(x)).Add(b)
```

and end up with

```
pow3, e1 := x.Pow(three)
mul, e2 := a.Mul(x)
add, e3 := pow3.Add(mul)
rval, e4 := add.Add(b)
// check that y^2 == rval
```

This makes the code hard to follow, what is the golang way to properly do this?

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fR4WdvYuiAF)

Answer (score 5):

Make your methods return only a single value, so they can be chained, and store the error value in that returned value, to check after.  Example:

```
type FieldElement struct {
    Num   int
    Prime int
    Error error
}

func (el *FieldElement) Add(o FieldElement) *FieldElement {
    if el.Error != nil {
        // An error already happened, so do nothing
        return el
    }
    if el.Prime != o.Prime {
        el.Error = errors.New("cannot operate on two numbers in different Fields")
    } else {
        el.Num = (el.Num + o.Num) & el.Prime
    }
    return el
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
    x.Add(...).Mul(...).Sub(...) // etc
    if x.Error != nil {
        // handle error here
    }
```

Comment: +1 for this way. There is another way to do it using panic/recover, but that feels hackish and non-Golang way to do it

Comment: @Metatrix: Yeah, don't do that. That would be some very non-idiomatic Go.

Comment: Agree with that solution but I prefer `x.Err` instead of `x.Error`, usually reserve Error for error interface implementation.

Comment: This is OK for designing your own APIs, but it's not much help working with libraries that all return `(something, error)`.